# Ansible - replace line in file

Tags: ansible

I'm really new to Ansible but I have a situation with replace module.

I tried my regex online https://regex101.com/ and it worked.

Then I tried the regex in my Ansible but it's not working.
I also tried to use lineInFile module.
Guess I'm somehow still thinking old way and not the right Ansible way. Therefore I'm not able to put this together.

```
- name: Update the CMakeLists, add -latomic
  replace:
    path: /home/{{ device_user }}/ros2_{{ ros2_distro }}/src/ros2/rcutils/CMakeLists.txt
    regexp: '^\s+target_link_libraries\(test_atomics_executable\s+\${PROJECT_NAME}'
    replace: '^\s+target_link_libraries\(test_atomics_executable\s+\${PROJECT_NAME} -latomic\)'
```

Those lines produces:

```
The error was: re.error: bad escape \s at position 1
```

I don't know why is that since the regex is ok, isn't it?
I'm trying to find exact match I know that there is only one line such as this.

The CMakeLists.txt where I'm trying to do my changes:

```
  ...
  target_link_libraries(test_atomics_executable ${PROJECT_NAME})
  if(HAVE_LIBATOMICS)
    target_link_libraries(test_atomics_executable atomic)
  endif()
  add_test(NAME test_atomics COMMAND test_atomics_executable)
  ...
```

Could you please tell me what I doing wrong?
*(Please don't bother to just link the docs I have been already there and I tried to read it.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error

```
 re.error: bad escape \s at position 1
```

points to the first position in the parameter `replace`

```
 replace: '^\s+target_link_libraries ... '
```

The parameter [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-replace) is not a regex. Try

```yaml
- replace:
    path: CMakeLists.txt
    regexp: '^\s+target_link_libraries\(test_atomics_executable\s+\${PROJECT_NAME}\)(.*)$'
    replace: '  target_link_libraries(test_atomics_executable ${PROJECT_NAME} -latomic)'
```

This should replace the first line in the file

```yaml
-  target_link_libraries(test_atomics_executable ${PROJECT_NAME})
+  target_link_libraries(test_atomics_executable ${PROJECT_NAME} -latomic)
```

Is this what you want? I'm not sure about the leading spacing.

Comment: Thank you, it worked nicely. That was exactly what I needed. Well, it's obvious there is a lot to learn for me. This was a huge step forward.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Vladimir Botka pointed out in his answer, your regex expression needs to account for
the ending parenthesis `)` after `\${PROJECT_NAME}` and it also needs a `$` at the end to assert the end of your exact match (you don't have to escape this ending `$`).

Also, if all occurrences of the line you want to replace are exactly `target_link_libraries(test_atomics_executable ${PROJECT_NAME})`, you don't need to quantify the space character (`\s+`). You can simply use:

`regexp: '^target_link_libraries\(test_atomics_executable \${PROJECT_NAME}\)$'`

or this (like @larsks pointed out), depending on if you still get an error while escaping `(` and `$` :

`regexp: '^target_link_libraries\\(test_atomics_executable \\${PROJECT_NAME}\\)$'`